# Taking a line from a text file and putting them into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a line in the following format:

```
Liam "!#123121" 32 "University of Southern California" "1312azasdas"
```

I want to split this line in python such that for each line in a file, there is a `name`, `age` and `university`. In the above example, '32' is the age, 'Liam' is the name and 'University...' is the University name. What could be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)! They're a little confusing to get your head around to start with, but they're awesome. Too much to explain in full here, but a brief demo on your specific example:

```
import re

t = 'Liam "!#123121" 32 "University of Southern California" "1312azasdas"'

nau = re.match('([A-Za-z]+) ".*" ([0-9]+) "([A-Za-z ]+)" .*', t)
nau.groups()

>> ('Liam', '32', 'University of Southern California')
```

Very brief breakdown of the regular expression:

1. Anything within round brackets is a 'group' - i.e. the bits you're interested in.
2. Anything in square brackets denotes a character set - which means 'match any of these characters', and the hyphen in A-Z means 'anything upper case between A and Z'.
3. The '+' after square brackets means that it's looking for 1 or more of the characters in the set, and only stops when it finds a character *not* in the set.
4. '.*' means match *anything*, but you'll notice that none of the .*'s I've used are in the groups - they're just used to skip irrelevant stuff *between* the groups.

Hoppe that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), set empty space as delimiter and put in `"` for your quote character. This is fairly simple, just experiment and test a bit.